# Drage and move on click a control on Canvas wpf

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, wpf-controls

I want to Drag Move a `userControl` which is in a canvas(named as `grd`) and that canvas is in a larger canvas on which there are a lot of other controls. I am using this code, but it does not work. I am making `mouseDown` and `MouseUp`events of `userControl` and a `MouseMve` event of the larger canvas which has a lot of controls.

Where is the problem?

```
Dim _pressed As Boolean = False
Dim grd As Canvas
Dim mp As Point

Private Sub DeviceIcon_MouseLeftButtonDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
    _pressed = True
    grd = sender
    mp = mousePosition
End Sub

Private Sub DeviceIcon_MouseLeftButtonUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
    _pressed = False
End Sub

Private Sub gridimgFloor_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs) Handles gridimgFloor.MouseMove
    If _pressed = False Then Exit Sub
    Dim nmp As Point = mousePosition

    Dim _x As Integer = nmp.X - mp.X
    Dim _y As Integer = nmp.Y - mp.Y

    Dim thk As Thickness = grd.Margin
    thk.Left = thk.Left + _x
    thk.Top = thk.Top + _y
    grd.Margin = thk

    mp = nmp


End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you set `mousePosition`? In the code you show, it's never initialized. You should use the position from the event args.

Comment: i am getting mouse position through this methode " mousePosition "
how can i get mouse postioon through event args ?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `mousePosition` was a method (thanks to the dumb VB syntax). You should use `e.GetPosition(parentControl)`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas Levesque .
can you plz post as answer so that i can mark it as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `e.GetPosition(parentControl)` to get the position from the event args.